# Why is removeClass not working - what have I coded wrong?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

If my html is

```
<form class="form1" id="registerPublicFRM" action="" method="post">
    <label for="firstname">First name:</label><div class="errRnd"><input name="firstname" id="firstname" size="28" type="text"></div>       
     <input value="Register" type="submit">
</form>
```

Shouldn't running this jquery

```
$('#registerPublicFRM .errRnd').removeClass('errRnd');
```

turn `class="errRnd"` into `class=""` ?

As is, it remains

```
<div class="errRnd">
```

Comment: How do you know it remains? Have you perhaps looked at the original page source? Assuming the class is actually not removed, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Are you viewing the source? Or are you viewing a DOM tool in your developer tools for your browser? The source will never change, you need to view the updated DOM.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JPufu/

Comment: The class errRnd places a red border around the filed, which should disappear. When I Ctrl-A the browser page, and view the source, the class is still "errRnd". Thanks guys.

Comment: make sure included jQuery lib?  and run the script in the document.ready.

Comment: @Shaun viewing the source usually shows the original source that haven't been modified by jquery. Right click and click "inspect element" to see the current state of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys. My bad - I had a stray piece of code later in the func that was also adding a border.